# How to solve "undefined symbol: qt_x11Data" error?

Tags: qt, avogadro

I have just installed avogadro.
When I try to launch the program by "./avogadro" command, it does not launch but gives the following error:

```
./avogadro: symbol lookup error: /lib64/libQtOpenGL.so.4: undefined symbol: qt_x11Data
```

Does anyone know how this error is caused and how to fix it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hmm maybe you need to check your path variables, or if the program is installed correctly. It seems that it can't find the necessary lib.

Comment: Could you give some more specific guide? which lib cannot be found by the program? libQtOpenGL.so.4? libQtOpenGL.so.4 is in /usr/lib. Even if I add it to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH, the same error comes out.

Comment: As I understand, I should first find where the undefined symbol “qt_x11Data” is defined. If it is define in a certain lib, then I need to add the lib to PATH. But how to track the undefined symbol?

Comment: I used ldd the check  libQtOpenGL.so.4 by " ldd -r /usr/lib64/libQtOpenGL.so.4" and get:                                                                                                                     undefined symbol: _ZN7QWidget8x11EventEP7_XEvent (/usr/lib64/libQtOpenGL.so.4)
undefined symbol: qt_x11Data (/usr/lib64/libQtOpenGL.so.4)
...........                                                                                                                                Obviously  qt_x11Data is in the list. But I got no idea what to do next.